# spring-kafka: DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer vs RetryTopicConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-retry

How are `DefaultErrorHandler` and `RetryTopicConfiguration/Builder` related? Can they work together or does one take precedence over the other?

I am trying to setup my consumption such that

1. Retry a certain number of times (`FixedBackOff(attempts = 3, interval = 5s)`)
2. Use a single topic for retry (`RetryTopicConfiguration.useSingleTopicForFixedDelays` works)
3. Customize the name of the retry topic (say `main-topic-name.retry`). Have not found any class/method that lets me do that.
4. If the retries are exhausted, then post to a dead letter with a customized name (`main-topic-name.deadLetter`). `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` second parameter `BiFunction` should work but looks like the DL topic has to created beforehand. Not entirely sure.

**Observations**

- If I use `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` without retry related property configuration, I am able to retry with the hard-coded `FixedBackOff` (`return new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer, new FixedBackOff(5000, 3));`)
- If I use `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` **with** retry related property configuration, the above hard-coded backoff is overridden. I am puzzled how the override happens even though I am supplying a configured error handler instance.
- By using `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` only, I don't get a separate retry topic.
- By using `RetryTopicConfiguration` (with or without recoverer), I get a retry topic, not with the name I want but default one. However, the dead letter topic used is not mine, the one supplied in `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` but the default one (`....-dlt`)

I am hoping people would have come across this and have a found a solution to the way I intend to setup my consumption (numbered list above).

Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be more about topic naming than about `DeadLetterPubishingRecoverer`.

If you just need to change the topics' suffix, such as `main-topic-name.retry` and `main-topic-name.deadLetter`, you can use methods in the `RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder`, such as:

```java
@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration myRetryTopic(KafkaTemplate<String, MyOtherPojo> template) {
    return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
            .newInstance()
            .useSingleTopicForFixedDelays()
            .retryTopicSuffix(".retry")
            .dltTopicSuffix(".deadletter")
            .create(template);
}
```

If you need more customization than that, you can also provide a `RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory`.

Refer to the feature's topic naming documentation - versions [2.8.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.8/reference/html/#topic-naming) and [2.9.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#topic-naming) for more details.

About the interaction with `DefaultErrorHandler` and `DeadLetterPubishingRecoverer`, the way the feature works is the framework will setup its own `DEH` and `DLPR` to handle record forwarding to the retry topics and dlt.

You can customize these components if necessary - for `2.9.x` see [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-config) of the documentation on how to configure it.

Comment: Thanks @Tomaz. I was able to get it working with custom topic names.

Comment: Does the framework use DEH/DLPR internally in RetryTopicConfiguration for it to retry and publish to retry topic, and on exhaustion publish to DLT?

Comment: Exactly, the framework creates and configures these components to handle record forwarding. You can see more details in [ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/ListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.java) and [DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory.java)

Comment: Does that mean RetryTopicConfiguration and RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory cannot be used together? Can raise a separate question if desired.